# Too Many Redirects on Index.php Page

Tags: php, loops, redirect, header

So I just downloaded a git repo and I am not really great at PHP so that's why I am here.

I am getting too many redirects on page error.

This error to be exact : "Too many redirects occurred trying to open “mysite.com”. This might occur if you open a page that is redirected to open another page which then is redirected to open the original page. "

I have also tried opening on Firefox and Chrome browser but no luck.

My index.php code is :

```
<?php

header('X-Frame-Options: DENY'); 
$init=true;
include './inc/start.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title><?php echo $settings['title'].' - '.$settings['description']; ?></title>

    <?php include './js/includer.php'; ?>
  </head>
  <body>
    <?php include './themes/'.$settings['activeTheme'].'/frontpage.php'; ?>
  </body>
</html>
<?php include './inc/end.php'; ?>
```

My inc/start.php is :

```
<?php


if (!isset($init)) exit();



session_start();

$included=true;
$conf_c=false;
include './inc/db-conf.php';
if ($conf_c==false) {
  header('Location: ./install/');
  exit();
}
include './inc/wallet_driver.php';
$wallet=new jsonRPCClient($driver_login);
include './inc/functions.php';


if (empty($_GET['unique'])) {
  if (!empty($_COOKIE['unique_D_']) && mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `players` WHERE `hash`='".prot($_COOKIE['unique_D_'])."' LIMIT 1"))!=0) {
    header('Location: ./?unique='.$_COOKIE['unique_D_'].'# Do Not Share This URL!');
    exit();  
  }
  newPlayer($wallet);
}
else { // !empty($_GET['unique'])
  if (mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `players` WHERE `hash`='".prot($_GET['unique'])."' LIMIT 1"))!=0) {
    $player=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `players` WHERE `hash`='".prot($_GET['unique'])."' LIMIT 1"));
    $unique=prot($_GET['unique']);
    setcookie('unique_D_',prot($_GET['unique']),(time()+60*60*24*365*5),'/');  
  }
  else {
    setcookie('unique_D_',false,(time()-10000),'/');
    header('Location: ./');    
    exit();
  }
}


if ($player['password']!='' && (empty($_COOKIE['protected_D_']) || $_COOKIE['protected_D_']!=$player['password'])) {  
  if (isset($_GET['bad_'])) echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert(\'Wrong password!\')</script>';
  echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location.href=\'./content/requestAccess.php?_unique='.$unique.'&pass=\'+prompt(\'This URL is password protected. Please, enter password:\');</script>';
  exit();
}

$settings=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `system` WHERE `id`=1 LIMIT 1"));

if (!file_exists('./themes/'.$settings['activeTheme'].'/main.css') || !file_exists('./themes/'.$settings['activeTheme'].'/frontpage.php')) {
  echo '<b>Error!</b> Can\'t load active theme.';
  exit();
}
?>
```

Please help teach what's wrong in code and how can I fix it. I believe the code in start.php is invoking to go to index.php again and that is calling start.php again and redirect loop is getting infinite.

Thanks

Comment: You could improve your question by adding the exact error, limiting the code to the relevant parts, and explaining what the code is supposed to be doing.

Comment: which type of error share it

Comment: Too many redirects occurred trying to open “mysite.com”. This might occur if you open a page that is redirected to open another page which then is redirected to open the original page. @Bhargav

Comment: what server do you use? apach/nginx ? please add your configuration & .htaccess, you may have trouble in there.
Also please try to use some output (or xdebug) to trace what actually happens, there are too many things in your code. example: Maybe you unable to load config and going to ./install and its absent so redirect to index and... loop